# RowKey of DataTable is null when calling onCellEdit

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, datatable, lazy-loading

I have a Primefaces 6.0 `DataTable` working with a `LazyDataModel` bean. After I changed to the lazy implementation, the cell edition stopped working. 
The reason for that is whenever I call my `onCellEdit` method, and try to get the clicked row contents by calling `event.getRowkey()` , I get a `null` object.
As per [Primefaces Documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_1.pdf) I'm have a `rowKey` attribute to bind the tuple with the bean value, but it doesn't seems to work.

EDIT: I can update the value now, but the dataTable doesn't reload the cell UiElement. To see the changes i have to F5 the page.

### Here is my ata.xhtml DATATABLE(Sanitized)

```
<p:tabView id="tab" value="#{setorMB.listaSetor}" var="tabView" 
    activeIndex="#{ataGerencialMB.activeTabIndex}">
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{ataGerencialMB.onTabChange}"
            update="tab ,formListagemCapacitacao" />
    <p:tab title="#{tabView.sigla}">
        <p:dataTable    id="dtCapacitacao" 
                value="#{ataGerencialMB.lazyModelAtaGerencial}"
                var="gerencial"  
                lazy="true"
                paginator="true" 
                rows="#{Config.NUM_ROWS}"
                currentPageReportTemplate="#{Config.CURRENT_PAGE_REPORT_TEMPLATE}"
                paginatorTemplate="#{Config.PAGINATOR_TEMPLATE}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="#{Config.ROWS_PER_PAGE_TEMPLATE}"
                sortBy="#{gerencial.idAta}" 
                sortOrder="ascending"
                reflow="true" 
                editable="true" 
                editMode="cell"
                rowKey="#{gerencial.idAta}">

        <p:ajax event="cellEdit"
                listener="#{ataGerencialMB.onCellEdit}" oncomplete="onCellEdit()"/>

        <p:column>
            <p:rowToggler/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Tipo Assunto" >
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{gerencial.tipo}" 
                                  rendered="true" />
                </f:facet>

                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputTextarea id="tipo" 
                       value="#{gerencial.tipo}" 
                       style="width:96%" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
      </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

### Class that extends the LazyDataModel AtaGerencialLazyDataModel

```
public class AtaGerencialLazyDataModel extends LazyDataModel<AtaGerencialBean> {

AtaGerencialBusiness ataBusiness = new AtaGerencialBusiness();
Map<String, Object> customFilters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
private List<AtaGerencialBean> listaAtaGerencialBean = new ArrayList<AtaGerencialBean>();

public AtaGerencialLazyDataModel(){
    this.setRowCount(ataBusiness.getAtaGerencialTotalCount(null));
}

public AtaGerencialLazyDataModel(SetorBean setor){
    customFilters.put("setor", setor);
    this.setRowCount(ataBusiness.getAtaGerencialTotalCount(customFilters));
}

@Override
public List<AtaGerencialBean> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
        SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters){
    List<AtaGerencialBean> list = ataBusiness.fetchLazyAtaGerencial(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, customFilters);
    this.setRowCount(ataBusiness.getAtaGerencialTotalCount(customFilters));
    setListaAtaGerencialBean(list);
    setWrappedData(list);
    return list;
}

@Override
public AtaGerencialBean getRowData(String rowKey){
    try{
        long id = Long.parseLong(rowKey);
        for (AtaGerencialBean bean : listaAtaGerencialBean) {
            if (bean.getIdAta() == id){
                return bean;
            }

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;

}

@Override
public Object getRowKey(AtaGerencialBean p) {
    return p.getIdAta();
}

public List<AtaGerencialBean> getListaAtaGerencialBean() {
    return listaAtaGerencialBean;
}

public void setListaAtaGerencialBean(
        List<AtaGerencialBean> listaAtaGerencialBean) {
    this.listaAtaGerencialBean = listaAtaGerencialBean;
}

}
```

### The onCellEdit method

```
 @ManagedBean
 @ViewScoped
 public class AtaGerencialMB extends MB<AtaGerencialBean, 
 AtaGerencialBusiness> {

     private LazyDataModel<AtaGerencialBean> lazyModelAtaGerencial;    

     @SuppressWarnings("unused")
     public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
      try{
        DataTable controladorTabela = (DataTable) event.getComponent();
        //rowindex is fine, it brings the index of the edited row in the 
 datatable (from 0 onwards)
        Integer rowIndex = event.getRowIndex();
        String rowKey = event.getRowKey();

        //rowKey is always null
        System.out.println("rowKey value:" + rowKey);

        AtaGerencialBean entity = (AtaGerencialBean) controladorTabela.getRowData(event.getRowKey());
        this.setRegistroDefinido(entity);
        super.atualizar();
    }catch(NullPointerException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

  }
}
```

### EDIT

I was able to circumvent the problem by NOT using the `rowKey` to retrieve the data and modifying the `onCellEdit` method to get the data from the `Datamodel` inside the `Datatable`.

I am not sure whether it is a good/bad practice, or if that's how you're supposed to retrieve the row when using LazyLoading.

Also, following @Kukeltje suggestion, I am now using [PRIMEFACES 6.2](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_1.pdf)

#### Modified onCellEdit method

```
    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class AtaGerencialMB extends MB<AtaGerencialBean, AtaGerencialBusiness> {

   private LazyDataModel<AtaGerencialBean> lazyModelAtaGerencial;    
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
            try{
                DataTable controladorTabela = (DataTable) event.getComponent();
                DataModel dm = (DataModel) controladorTabela.getValue();
                AtaGerencialBean entity = (AtaGerencialBean) dm.getRowData();           
                this.setRegistroDefinido(entity);
                super.atualizar();
            }catch(NullPointerException ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: So you did NOT try PrimeFaces 6.2? Why  not?

Comment: Hey @Kukeltje, after your observation, I tested with 6.2 , the same problem occurs.

Comment: And it works if you don't use a tabview?

Comment: @Kukeltje it doesn't. I left only the Datatable and the div containing it, however rowKey is still nulll after onCellEdit call.

Comment: The bounty is confusing. This question seems to be already answered and accepted before the bounty started. Do you actually have an open question or not?

Comment: I could solve the my problem, but still am not able to get the value of  `rowKey`. The only way It seems to work is by setting  selectionMode="single" on the datatable. I was hoping someone had a better solution. Should I remove the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to circumvent the problem by NOT using the `rowKey` to retrieve the data and modifying the `onCellEdit` method to get the data from the `Datamodel` inside the `Datatable`.

I am not sure whether it is a good/bad practice, or if that's how you're supposed to retrieve the row when using LazyLoading.

Also, following @Kukeltje suggestion, I am now using [PRIMEFACES 6.2](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf)

### Modified onCellEdit method

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
        try{
            DataTable controladorTabela = (DataTable) event.getComponent();
            DataModel dm = (DataModel) controladorTabela.getValue();
            AtaGerencialBean entity = (AtaGerencialBean) dm.getRowData();           
            this.setRegistroDefinido(entity);
            super.atualizar();
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `selectionMode="single" disabledSelection="true"` to `p:datatable` solves the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2688

You may refer to this issue on github. You should enable selection for your datatable